# Object var vs Function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

What is the difference between these 2 types of structures

```
var bar = { 
    something : value,
    execute : function() { /* Whatever */ }
}

function foo() {    
    this.something = value;
    this.execute = function() { /* Whatever */ };
}
```

My reasoning is that bar is a static object, and foo is a regular object that has to be created calling the new constructor

Is that correct ? Or not really

Comment: It's correct as long as you see it only as a metaphor to compare with other languages.

Comment: yes, that looks right

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I'm sure the present question is a duplicate, we seem to see it multiple times a day, but probably not of the question you link to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between declaring javascript objects with var vs. with function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969689/what-is-the-difference-between-declaring-javascript-objects-with-var-vs-with-fu)

Comment: Please clarify your question. There is no such thing in javascript as a static object.  Are you asking about the finer points of the difference between an object and a function? Are you asking about the difference between using object literal syntax `{}` and `new`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean what's the difference between `bar` (as you declared it) and

```
var bar2 = new foo();
```

There's not a lot of difference between `bar` and `bar2`, other than that the prototype for `bar` will always be the prototype property of `Object` (as if you had written `var bar = new Object(); bar.something = value; bar.execute = function() {...}`), while the prototype for `bar2` will be whatever is assigned to the `prototype` property of `foo` (or the prototype property of `Object` by default).

Other than the issue of prototypes, writing a constructor function is mostly a matter of convenience.

Note that with the constructor approach, you can use the prototype to advantage:

```
function foo() {    
    this.something = value;
}

foo.prototype.execute = function() { /* Whatever */ };
```

Then all instances of `foo` share the same `execute` function. This is much more space efficient than having a new function object for each `foo` object. (Of course, if you're only creating one of these, there's not much advantage.)